# Why do I get different results with split() and isdigit()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got two different results.

The only thing that's different between them is `split()` and `split(",")`.

---

```
grade2 = "34 48 41 47 a1"
grade_list3 = [int(n) for n in grade2.split() if n.isdigit()]
grade_list3
[34, 48, 41, 47]
```

---

```
grade2 = "34, 48, 41, 47, a1"
grade_list3 = [int(n) for n in grade2.split(",") if n.isdigit()]
grade_list3
[34]
```

---

Why is that?

Comment: `" "` isn't a digit

Comment: Because `"48".isdigit()` returns True but `" 48'.isdigit()` (note extra space before number) returns False. You could try something like `[int(n) for n in grade2.split(",") if n.strip().isdigit()]` instead.

Comment: What steps have you taken to figure this out alone? Did you try to print the result of `split` to see how the strings look like? Did you try to call `isdigit` on each one separately?

Comment: @Heike or just `split(", ")`...

Comment: "the only thing that different between them is split() and split(",")" That is not true. In the first case, items are only separated by the split-separator; in the second case, items are separated by the split-separator *and* a space.

Comment: thanks guys, i didn't know " " would be a matter.. and i got it thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

`split()` takes two optional parameteres: `separator` and `maxsplit`.
`separator` Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string such as commas, or whitespaces. The default value for the separator is the whitespace.
`maxsplit` Specifies how many splits to do. Default value is -1, which is "all occurrences"

Tn the first part of the code, the function `split()` takes the string `grade2` and split the string using the whitespaces between the numbers:

```
grade2 = "34 48 41 47 a1"
print(grade2.split())
['34', '48', '41', '47', 'a1']
```

While in the second part of the code, `split()` takes the input string `grade2` and split it using the comma and the resulting list will look like this:

```
grade2 = "34, 48, 41, 47, a1"
print(grade2.split(","))
['34', ' 48', ' 41', ' 47', ' a1']
```

Note the leading spaces in `' 48'`, `' 41'`, `' 47'`, and `' a1'`. Now the string `' 48'` is not a digit because it contains a space.

You can fix the issue in. several ways. You could for example
remove any spaces from the original string before `split(',')`:

`enter code here`grade2 = grade2.replace(" ","")

or `strip()` spaces after `split(',')`:

```
grade_list3 = [int(n.strip()) for n in grade2.split(',') if n.strip().isdigit()]
```

or split using ', ' as a delimiter: `split(', ')`:

```
grade2 = "34, 48, 41, 47, a1"
grade_list3 = [int(n) for n in grade2.split(", ") if n.isdigit()]
```

and of course there are other ways...

Comment: I think it would be better to elaborate with some clear explanation ***why*** is that a problem. OP is obviously a beginner and your above answer might not be so clear and possibly confuse even more

Comment: Ofcourse. My answer was a placeholder. I was buying a sandwich :-) Now I have more time to expand the answer... but I think there is a good one already. So I will edit my placeholder...

Comment: oh my god thanks. I am a beginner  of python I just started python3 a week ago haha i appreciate your kind answer